# How to remove extra space between side-by-side elements when the right element is center-aligned multi-line text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm implementing a header with elements side-by-side - icon on the left and title on the right.

The title is center-aligned.

When the screen is narrowed and the title wraps onto the next line, a space is created between the icon and title.

[image: Demo image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the space is part of the content (it's not padding or margin).

How can I get the title to sit against the icon even when the title wraps onto a new line?

Here is the basic HTML and CSS to reproduce:

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <svg class="svg" height="50" width="50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </svg> 
  <h1 class="title">The title of the page</h1>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  width: 320px; /* simulate mobile width */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Codepen link to try it out: https://codepen.io/JayC_IRL/pen/VwKoJVQ

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible with CSS (and it is hard with javascript). ( I would like to be wrong, )